# Cast as INT check SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I need to update a column in a table. But only where the cast to an INT fails.

I have the following so far - but this updates all the records.

```
begin try
    select cast(customerid as int) from Table_staging;
end try
begin catch
update Table_staging
set incorrectformat = 0
end catch
```

Comment: Yes, DBMS and version would be useful.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` might be helpful but it has caveats. Read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Table_staging
set incorrectformat = 0
where not customerid like '%[^0-9]%'
```

should be sufficient. Basically, we mark `incorrectformat` for any row where `customerid` is *not* a string that contains any number of characters, then a character *not* in the set 0-9, than any number of characters.

I.e. the values that don't match this are precisely the ones only containing digits.

---

And the main issue with `ISNUMERIC` is that it answers a question that I don't believe anyone would ever, rightfully, ask - "Can this character string be converted to *any* of the numeric data types? I don't care which of those types it can be converted to, and there's no need to tell me which ones in response either"